# Bash execute another command and enter input automatically

Tags: bash, input

I have a script when running it with `./script.sh` it prints something in the console, then asks for a user input `username?`. After writing my username it asks a lot of other things which I have to write to the console.

I have one case where I have exactly the same input over and over again.
I want to write a second script that calls the first one and automatically puts in this input into the first script, so I only need to call the second script.

How can I achieve that? I know how I can call the first script from the second script but I have no idea where to put the input.

Comment: If it's only a single input your can do `echo someusername | ./script.sh`

Comment: Take a look at the `yes` command. It will write the same answer repeatedly to its output, which you can pipe to the script's input.

Comment: take a look at tools like [tag:expect] (for [tag:tcl]) or [tag:pexpect] (for [tag:python]). or try my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/) (for shell). they are all designed to interact with other programs in a programmable way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's reading from stdin for things like the password too, then you should be able to just put all your answers as lines in a file and redirect the script input from there.

```
./script.sh < answers.txt
```

A lot of apps won't accept passwords that way, though...